# disabling slide in particular direction angularjs ionic framework

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to *angularjs* and creating app for the first time in angularjs using *ionic framework*. I have created an ionic app using the following command:

```
$ ionic start myApp sidemenu
```

The app has been created properly with left menu kept under sliding so the main view slides to right on menu button clicked. The sliding works when the main view is dragged using gestures or mouse pointer.

I want to disable the dragging in direction to right to open the side menu.
The side menu should can be opened only by clicking the menu button and can be closed using menubutton or swipe in left direction or dragging with mouse on left direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use this:

```
<ion-side-menu-content drag-content="false">

</ion-side-menu-content>
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you use the beta 10+ version**, you can do it using :

```
<ion-side-menu-content drag-content="false">
    <!-- ... -->
</ion-side-menu-content>
```

You can check out the [beta10 release notes](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#100-beta10-hafnium-heron-2014-07-25) > Bug fixes :

> sideMenu: 
>   when drag-content=false, allow drag-to-close
>   ([e3db0856](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/commit/e3db08563b445e92854b9e2d57e3b76671b1e731), closes [#1419](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1419))

Before Beta10 version, you can use it but you couldn't close the menu by swipe, just using the menu button.

Answer (score -1):

If you comment out this line in the ionic.bundle.js file or in your base files and rebuild the ionic.bundle.js it will stop the menu drag capability.

sideMenuCtrl.canDragContent(true);

Comment: Hacking the core of a framework is rarely a good solution. It is more to **improving the framework**, less to disable some features. Here already exist an option included the framework.